# SuppressWarnings doesn't work with Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm trying to suppress the warning "Either override Object.equals(Object), or totally rename the method to prevent any confusion." because it is implemented because of Hibernate's UserType.

Neither of the following works:

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = "squid:S1201")
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = "S1201")
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("S1201")
```

or

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(
        value = "SuspiciousEqualsMethodName",
        justification = "Hibernate UserType equals method."
)
```

or

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(
        value = "SuspiciousEqualsMethodName",
        justification = "Hibernate UserType equals method."
)
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.SuspiciousEqualsMethodName")
```

Any ideas?

SonarQube Version 5.1.2 - LGPL v3 - Community with Java plugin v3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've upgraded to **SonarQube 5.6.2** and **Java Plugin 4.2** and now it seems work.

Answer (score 1):

Per [SONARJAVA-57](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-57), it should be `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1201")`

Comment: And [Java FAQ](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ#JavaFAQ-SuppressWarnings) states "SINCE 2.8 of Java Plugin, you can also use @SuppressWarnings annotation with a list of rule keys: @SuppressWarnings("squid:S2078") or  @SuppressWarnings({"squid:S2078", "squid:S2076"}). " so it should work with "squid:S1201" or "S1201".

Comment: You must use the java.lang.SuppressWarnings annotation and not the one provided by Findbugs.

Comment: I checked them all and I am using the java.lang version. (And I removed the few FindBugs-ones)

Comment: No more suggestions?